# How to Toggle the name with the "OnClick" feature of the button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, toggle

If the "`data-count-type`" value is `0` when the button is clicked, I want to write the "`data-charactercount`" value into the button.

When I click the button again, if the "`data-count-type`" value is `1`, I want to write the "`data-wordcount`" value into the button.

In summary, I want the text part of the button between 2 values to change each time the button is clicked. (Toggle)

There is a little error in the code so it doesn't work. What arrangement should I do?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-count-type="0" data-wordcount="15 Words" data-charactercount="50 Character" onclick="( (this.getAttribute('data-count-type')==0) ? this.innerText = this.getAttribute('data-wordcount'), this.setAttribute('data-count-type',1)  : this.getAttribute('data-charactercount'), this.setAttribute('data-count-type',0) )">BUTTON</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my best understanding,

You are trying to create a button where you will access the value of **data-count-type**. If **data-count-type** is 0 then the button should change the inner text with the value of **data-charactercount** AND if **data-count-type** is 1 then the button should change the inner text with the value of **data-wordcount**

Here is a snippet that performs the above-discribed behavior using inline JS.

**NOTE:** For easy understanding, I have below snippet with 2 button, 1 button is set with **data-count-type = 0** and second one is set with **data-count-type = 1**. But the inline script code for both is the same.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-count-type="1" data-wordcount="15 Words" data-charactercount="50 Character" onclick="
    if(this.getAttribute('data-count-type')==0){
        this.innerText = this.getAttribute('data-charactercount');
    } else if (this.getAttribute('data-count-type')==1){
        this.innerText = this.getAttribute('data-wordcount');
    }else{
    }
">BUTTON with data-count-type value 1</button>

<br>
<br>

<button type="button" data-count-type="0" data-wordcount="15 Words" data-charactercount="50 Character" onclick="
    if(this.getAttribute('data-count-type')==0){
        this.innerText = this.getAttribute('data-charactercount');
    } else if (this.getAttribute('data-count-type')==1){
        this.innerText = this.getAttribute('data-wordcount');
    }else{
    }
">BUTTON with data-count-type value 0</button>
```

Comment: I fixed the problem myself. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can do this:

```js
$(function() {
   $('button').on('click', function() {
      var countType = $(this).data('countType');
      var wordCount = $(this).data('wordcount');
      var charCount = $(this).data('charactercount');
      var result = countType === 0
        ? wordCount 
        : charCount;
      $(this).data('countType', ++countType).text(result);
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-count-type="0" data-wordcount="15 Words" data-charactercount="50 Character">BUTTON</button>
```

Or inline:

```
<button type="button" data-count-type="0" data-wordcount="15 Words" data-charactercount="50 Character" 
onclick="
this.innerText = (this.dataset.countType==0) 
    ? this.dataset.wordcount 
    : this.dataset.charactercount;
this.dataset.countType = ++this.dataset.countType">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: I don't want it that way. I want to add it to onclick.

Comment: <button type="button" data-count-type="0" data-wordcount="444" data-charactercount="873" onclick="((this.getAttribute('data-count-type')==0) ? this.innerText = this.getAttribute('data-wordcount')  : this.innerText = this.getAttribute('data-charactercount') ); ((this.getAttribute('data-count-type')==0) ? this.setAttribute('data-count-type',1) : this.setAttribute('data-count-type',0))" ></button>      This code works. How can I shorten this code further.

Comment: See my updated answer, you can use `.dataset` to populate the data.

Comment: I fixed the problem myself. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are asking for but I'm guessing its something like this:

```js
function handleClick (e) {
  const target = $(e.target)
  
  if (Boolean(target.data('count-type'))) {
    target.text(target.data('wordcount'))
  } else {
    target.text(target.data('charactercount'))
  }
  
  target.data('count-type', !Boolean(target.data('count-type')))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-count-type="0" data-wordcount="15 Words" data-charactercount="50 Character" onclick="handleClick(event)">BUTTON</button>
```

---

### How this works

We created a function called `handleClick` that parses a parameter `e` this references the click event we also have a constant variable named `target` with a value of `$(e.target)` this is the target element (the element with the click event).

Then we have an `if` statement that checks the value of the `count-type` data attribute and changes the data type of the condition to a boolean if it is true it sets the target elements inner text to the value of `data-wordcount` if the condition is `false` then sets the inner text of the `target` to the value of `data-charactercount`.

Then we set `count-type` to not its value (e.g. if `true` = `false`, if `false` = `true`).

In the `HTML` we have an attribute named `onclick` that is set to the function we declared `handleClick(event)` and we are parsing the `event` to our function.

Comment: I fixed the problem myself. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button type="button" data-count-type="0" data-wordcount="15 Words" data-charactercount="50 Character" onclick="0==this.getAttribute('data-count-type')?this.innerText=this.getAttribute('data-wordcount'):this.innerText=this.getAttribute('data-charactercount'),0==this.getAttribute('data-count-type')?this.setAttribute('data-count-type',1):this.setAttribute('data-count-type',0);">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't use any jQuery